Can't call GitHub files with <script>
For some reason, when I call a raw GitHub file using
<script>

tags, it does not load, the repository IS public, is there another setting I need to mess with? I need to load many things from GitHub, such as images, scripts, and styles. These are all for an "appstore" for my Web Browser "Operating System", Universe.
The goal is to have an appstore "server" so the appstore is not downloaded with the users copy of the operating system, and I can also make updates and changes to the appstore without updating the entire operating system itself.

What specific URL did you use and how specifically did it fail?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

@David https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SaltedInteractiveDevGroup/Unvierse-Appstore/server/module.js
It failed because it just did not load with the page. As if I never called the script.

In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when loading the page, is a request made for the JavaScript resource?  What is the server's response?

@David I would have to check that out in 4th period, these chromebooks don't allow the inspect tool. That is my next period, heading there now.

@David I might just do it at home, too much of a hastle to do excel and redo all the stuff I undid on my os.

github repositories are not intended to act as a cdn. You can e.g publish your repo to npm or create a CDN link via a service like https://www.jsdelivr.com/github

When you load https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SaltedInteractiveDevGroup/Unvierse-Appstore/server/module.js, GitHub is adding these headers to the response:
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
x-content-type-options: nosniff

The X-Content-Type-Options response header does this:

nosniff
Blocks a request if the request destination is of type style and the MIME type is not text/css, or of type script and the MIME type is
not a JavaScript MIME type.

So there you are. If you check the browser developer tools, you'll see the request failing in network pane and some browsers like Firefox will also show an error message in console.
I guess that raw.githubusercontent.com is not meant to be used as application server, but to have access to source code.

The Raw GitHub service (rawgithub.com) used to re-host Git files with proper headers. Your best bet now a days is to use jsDelivr and have your repo provide a dist/ directory via NPM. A lot more steps, but it works.
